# не отправляется сообщение через бота телеграмм, при использовании очереди laravel

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot

Пишу бота для телеграм на Laravel. Через supervisor запустил worker очереди, вот конфиг:

```
[program:laravel-worker-www-root2]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/www-root2/data/www/binance/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-root2
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/www-root2/data/www/binance/worker.log
```

Так же через supervisor запустил выполнение artisan-команды, конфиг:

```
[program:binance-signal-bot]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/www-root2/data/www/sitedir/artisan myArtisanCommand
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-root2
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/www-root2/data/www/sitedir/my-artisan-command-log.log
```

Драйвер очреди database. В запущенной каманде при нужном условии создается событие, а в слушателе события создается задание для очереди, в котором вызывается отправка сообщения через телеграм бота, но сообщения не отправляются до тех пор пока не выполнть команду:

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

После этого все сообщения приходят разом, и так до следующего запуска команды. В логах воркера очереди ошибок нет, как и в логах laravel.
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Привет. Команда `queue:restart` необходима, чтобы перезапустить процесс очередей. Это необходимо в случае, если ты внес изменения в код, но они не вступят в силу, пока ты не перезапустишь очередь.

Comment: @ChaikinEvgenii, Привет) Да я это понимаю, только вот почему очередь отрабатывает, и задача уходит из очереди, но сообщение отправляется? я ведь не изменял код, я только пытался отправить сообщение

Comment: Сообщения в лог вываливаются какие-нибудь?

Comment: @ChaikinEvgenii, об ошибках сообщений нет, ставил логи в заданиях все выводится, но только сами сообщения не отправляются использую  вот эту [библиотеку](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk)